# Data is not inserted but response is 200 in Nodejs using mongoDB atlas?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, npm, mongodb-atlas

I am learning nodeJs. I am using mongoDB atlas database to perform the operations. I want to insert the user data but its not inserting into a collection.

Using postman i got 200 in response and "message :{} " My code is below please check and provide any solution.

**index.js**

```
      const express = require('express');
  const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
  const mongoose = require('mongoose');
  require('dotenv/config');
  const Tea = require('./models/tea')

  const app = express();
  app.use(express.json());
  var fs = require("fs");
  app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
  app.use(bodyParser.json());


  try {
    mongoose.connect("mongodb+srv://test:<test>@firstcluster.g9kk1.mongodb.net/glocoach?retryWrites=true&w=majority",
      {
        useNewUrlParser: true,
        useUnifiedTopology: true,
      }, (req, res) => {
        console.log("Connection Successfull!!"); 
        
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("Connection error");
  }


  app.post('/login', async (req, res)=> {
    
    try{
      const userTea = new Tea(req.body);
        await userTea.save();
        res.send(userTea);

    }catch(error){
      console.log();
      res.send({
        message : error
      })
    }
    
  })

  app.listen(3000, ()=> {
      console.log("Listening to 3000");
  });
```

**models/tea.js**

```
            const mongoose = require("mongoose"); //import mongoose

        // tea schema
        const TeaSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
            name: {type:String, required:true},
            age : Number
        });

        const Tea = mongoose.model('Tea', TeaSchema); //convert to model named Tea
        module.exports = Tea; //export for controller use
```

*postman*
[image]

**if i don't use the "userTea.save()" method**
then i got response in postman in console but still data is not inserted - ?

```
 try{
      const userTea = new Tea(req.body);
        // await userTea.save();
        res.send(userTea);
        console.log(req.body);

    }
```

[image]

Comment: could you log `req.body`  in try block ?

Comment: I tried but nothing is happening. Any other solution?

Comment: I updated my answer please see once.

Comment: try `Tea.create(req.body)` instead of `save`

Comment: Getting same issue.

Comment: hello - can you try and specify your database in the connection url ?